# Why is tidycensus area provided different that calculated by sf::_st_area()

Tags: r, r-sf, tidycensus, tigris, tiger-census

I am using the tidycensus R package to pull in census data and geometries. I want to be able to calculate population densities and have the results match what I see on [censusreporter.org](https://censusreporter.org/profiles/04000US48-texas/). I am noticing a difference between the geography variables returned from tidycenus compared to what I calculate myself using the sf package sf::st_area() function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidycensus)
census_api_key("my_api_key")
library(sf)
options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)

pop_texas <-
  get_acs(geography = 'state',
      variables = "B01003_001", # Total Population
      year = 2020, 
      survey = 'acs5', 
      keep_geo_vars = TRUE,
      geometry = TRUE) %>%
filter(GEOID == '48') # Filter to Texas
```

Since I included the keep_geo_vars argument as TRUE it returned an ALAND column which I believe is the correct area for the geography returned in square meters (m^2).

```
> pop_texas$ALAND %>% format(big.mark=",")
[1] "676,680,588,914"

# Conversion to square miles
> (pop_texas$ALAND / 1000000 / 2.5899881) %>% format(big.mark=",")
[1] "261,267.8"
```

When I convert the ALAND amount to square miles I get the same number as shown on censusreporter.org:

[image]

I have also tried to calculate the area using the sf::st_area() function, but I get a different result:

```
> sf::st_area(pop_texas) %>% format(big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)
[1] "688,276,954,146 [m^2]"

# Conversion to square miles
> (sf::st_area(pop_texas) / 1000000 / 2.5899881) %>%
+   as.numeric() %>%
+   format(big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)
[1] "265,745.2"
```

Please let me know if there is something I am missing to reconcile these numbers. I would expect to get the same results either directly through tidycensus or calculating the area using sf::st_area().

Right now I am off by a lot:

```
> (pop_texas$ALAND - as.numeric(st_area(pop_texas)) ) %>%
+   format(big.mark=",")
[1] "-11,596,365,232"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the "official" area of a shape like Texas you should always use the `ALAND` or published area value.  `st_area()` is using geometry to calculate the area of the polygon which is always going to be a simplified and imperfect representation of Texas (or any other area).  For smaller shapes (like Census tracts) the calculations will probably be pretty close; for larger shapes like states (especially those with complex coastal geography, like Texas) you're going to be further off.

Answer (score 0):

These differences are usually due to the CRS (the projection used on your `sf` objects). Some projections distort area, other projections distors the shape. See this to learn more [http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Distortion#:~:text=There%20are%20four%20main%20types,%2C%20direction%2C%20shape%20and%20area](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Distortion#:%7E:text=There%20are%20four%20main%20types,%2C%20direction%2C%20shape%20and%20area).